# (Another) What Statistical Test Should I Use?

Tags: statistical-significance, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, overlapping-data

If I ask 600 different people to rate 3 different images from 0-10 (i.e 3 samples of 200 people per image) and I calculate the mean scores per image as well as the overall mean for all 3 images, can I use a statistical test to claim the mean of image 1 is significantly greater than the overall mean?

Is there an overlapping test because people who voted in image 1 are also used in the calculation of the overall mean?

Would it make more sense to calculate the mean of image 1 vs the mean of the scores of all images not from image 1? Depending on normality etc use the Mann Whitney or 2 sample t test?

Comment: This sort of issue (subset-vs-all comparison) is addressed in several posts on site. I can't look right now but I'll try to find one.